# RGL widget not displayed in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, widget, rgl

I have been struggling for some hours trying to build a shiny app including a RGL widget.
I would like to have a sliderInput controlling an agecontrol evolution of a plot and the widget is not displayed.

Please find hereafter the code I am working on at the moment.

```
library(shiny)
library(rgl)


ui <- (fluidPage(
sliderInput("sld", label = "Slider", min = 0., max = 4*pi, value = 0., step = .1),
playwidgetOutput("control"),
 rglwidgetOutput("wdg")
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
save <- options(rgl.inShiny = TRUE)
on.exit(options(save))

# create data for widget
theta <- seq(0, 4*pi, len=100)
xyz <- cbind(sin(theta), cos(theta), sin(theta/2))
open3d()
lineid <- plot3d(xyz, type="l", alpha = 0, lwd = 5, col = "blue")["data"]
scene <- scene3d()
rgl.close()

output$wdg <- renderRglwidget({
rglwidget(scene, controllers = c("control"))
})
control <- ageControl(births = theta,
                    ages = c(-4*pi, -4*pi, 1-4*pi, 0, 0, 1),
                    objids = lineid,
                    alpha = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0))

output$control <- renderPlaywidget({
playwidget("wgd",control,
            respondTo = "sld")
})}
if (interactive()) shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/shinyRGL.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My understanding is that this package is no more up-to-date. Its functionalities are covered by rgl and shiny packages. Am I right?

Comment: @PorkChop Jean-Phi N is right. `shinyRGL` is deprecated. Now to use `rgl` in `shiny`, one uses some functions given in `rgl` itself.

Comment: Jean-Phi N, I don't know whether this can help but I have a [shiny app here](https://gist.github.com/stla/4811f891d2e1548ce659becfd0a8d266) using `rgl` and `sliderInput`'s. It works but it is more simple than yours.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent , Your shiny app is not using an agecontrol. I have considered a similar way to the one you have used but I am unsure about the performance (the example given is a reproducible example of a bigger project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a Shiny `sliderInput` to control things, the `playwidget` will not be displayed.  This is normal, and documented.

However, there's still a problem:  when I run your app, the slider doesn't appear to be controlling the display.  That looks like a bug in `rgl`, not in your code. Not sure what to advise...

Edited to add:  Nope, not an `rgl` bug.  In one spot you name the rgl widget as `wgd`, and in another as `wdg`.  Fix that typo, and your code works.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. That’s indeed my problem: the slider input is not controlling the display. Sorry if the initial question was not clear.

Comment: Found a typo in your code, see the edit to the answer.  Maybe `rgl` should complain about errors like this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I confirm this is working once corrected. I am a little ashamed for such an error! And I agree with your comment regarding rgl not raising this kind of error :-).